# Identify the total group in a Postgres grouping set

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I identify which row is the "total" one when using a `GROUPING SET`?

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    product TEXT NOT NULL,
    customer TEXT NOT NULL,
    cost NUMERIC NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO sales (product, customer, cost)
VALUES ('Igloo', 'John', 5000)
    , ('Igloo', 'John', 5000)
    , ('Donkey', 'John', 1000)
    , ('Donkey', 'Jane', 1000)
    , ('Mortgage', 'John''s Brother, Jim', 1000);
```

I want to sum sales across customer, product and overall:

```
SELECT product, customer, SUM(cost)
FROM sales
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((product), (customer), ())
ORDER BY GROUPING(product, customer);
```

Giving this result:

```
product  customer            sum
-------- ------------------- -----
Donkey   (null)              2000
Igloo    (null)              10000
Mortgage (null)              1000
(null)   Jane                1000
(null)   John                11000
(null)   John's Brother, Jim 1000
(null)   (null)              13000
```

I want to add an `is_total` column, is there any way of getting the "empty" grouping set with `GROUPING()`? Ideally I would do this but it's not valid:

```
SELECT product
, customer
, sum(cost)
, GROUPING(()) == 0 AS is_total
FROM sales
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((product), (customer), ())
ORDER BY GROUPING(product, customer);
```

I'm aware I can do this:

```
SELECT product
, customer
, sum(cost)
, GROUPING(product, customer) = 3 AS is_total
FROM sales
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((product), (customer), ())
ORDER BY GROUPING(product, customer);
```

But ideally I wouldn't as my query is very complicated and the groups are dynamically created. This is just a simple example.

SQLFiddle here if helps: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f5ba5/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, `coalesce()` is sufficient:

```
select coalesce(product, customer, 'Total')
```

More formally, you can use `grouping()`:

```
select (case when grouping(product) = 0 then product
             when grouping(customer) = 0 then customer
             else 'Total'
        end) as the_key
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, I was hoping something like `GROUPING(())` was possible, but it seems not. Your solution is definitely better than what I was doing anyway. Thanks Gordon.